# How can I create a blend scatter/stroked effect with posed photos?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

Yesterday I went to a local art market and found some work I really liked:

[image: In de wolken 80x80cm op basis van acryl]
<sup>[In de wolken 80x80cm op basis van acryl by Kitty Meijering](http://kittymeijering.jalbum.net/Kitty%20Meijering/nieuw/)</sup>

It made me wonder how I might achieve a similar effect in Photoshop, but I could not find anything online. So, if anybody could point me in the right direction it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Corel's Painter creates the feel of natural media much easier and better.

Comment: I see, however I do not own corel nor have any experience with it. I'm afraid I'm really  looking for a photoshop solution.

Comment: Understood. :) But.. you could save money on a hammer and build a house with only a pair of pliers... That doesn't make it fun or a worthwhile venture ;) Corel has free demos. Honestly, the amount of work needed in Photoshop is completely ridiculous when compared to Painter, regardless of any experience in either app. Most users can launch Painter and be creating natural-media-like images in a matter of minutes.

Comment: Although I wouldn't agree with photoshop being the metaphorical equivalent of pliers when building houses :), I do think Painter does a amazing job in emulating real brush strokes. A lot of digital artists like Photoshop because of the ease of customization you have with brushes and the vast resources there are for brushes. If you asked digital painters I honestly think it would be close to split among their tool of preference, but when it comes to imitating the feel of canvas Painter is slightly ahead of Photoshop

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best free resource to get started digital painting with Photoshop is [Ctrl + Paint](http://ctrlpaint.com/). Before watching this magician, Matt Kohr, explain how painting works on Photoshop I thought painting was really out of reach as a hobby. As said in the comments, I really think Corel Painter might be slightly better in terms of imitating the real feel of canvas. If you have a skill set already in Photoshop though, painting is not that difficult to pick up.

To understand how to make brushes that would imitate the above painting you might want to start with this [video on Ctrl+Paint](https://matt-kohr.squarespace.com/dp101-2) and build your way towards researching how to create custom brushes in Photoshop